# Unable to update UILabel using dispatch_async method in swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I am setting json string value to UILabel using dispatch_async method. But Its unable to show updated value , but when I am printing label text, its showing updated value. here is my code-

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     get_detail_postmethod(url, params: params)
}

 func get_detail_postmethod(url: String, params: String) {
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: url)!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    let postString = params
    print("param=\(params)")
    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in
        guard error == nil && data != nil else {                                                          // check for fundamental networking error
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        if let httpStatus = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse where httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
            print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
            print("response = \(response)")

        }

        let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        print("responseString = \(responseString)")
        do{
            let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .AllowFragments)
            print(json)
           if let success = json["success"] as? Int
            {
            if((success) == 1){

             self.extract_json(data!)

            }
            else{

            }
            }

        }catch {
            print("Error with Json: \(error)")
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

and below code for extract json data and set String value to UILabel-

```
func extract_json(jsonData:NSData)
{
    let json: AnyObject?
    do {
        json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: [])
        print("full data \(json!)")
    } catch {
        json = nil
        return
    }
    let user_object = json!["opportunity_master"] as! NSArray
    let data_block = user_object[0] as? NSDictionary
    self.opp_title = (data_block!["opportunity_title"] as? String)!
    self.event_sdate = (data_block!["event_start_date"] as? String)!

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        print(self.opp_title)
        self.Event_title.text? = self.opp_title
        self.Txt_event_date.text = self.event_sdate
        self.Event_title.setNeedsDisplay()

        print("event title label \(self.Event_title.text)")

    })

}
```

**I am not able to update values. Please suggest is there any other way to implement update UiLabel text.**

Comment: Please anybody help me to solve this..

Comment: Show me Log of event title label.

Comment: even put a screenshot of log,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is solved by calling Viewcontroller like this-

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let Opprt_Controller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Opprtunity_Event") as! Opportunity_Event

    self.navigationController!.pushViewController(Opprt_Controller, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try the below code to update your Label :**

```
NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock({ () -> Void in
        print(self.opp_title)
        self.Event_title.text? = self.opp_title
        self.Txt_event_date.text = self.event_sdate
        self.Event_title.setNeedsDisplay()
        print("event title label \(self.Event_title.text)") 

})
```

Comment: it did not happen , please give other solution for this

Answer (score 0):

call get_detail_postmethod(url, params: params) method in viewDidAppear instead of viewDidLoad.

Comment: I'm not able to get previous controller data  value in view Did Appear method.

Comment: Try  self.Event_title.text  instead self.Event_title.text?

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error in your `dispatch_async` method. Update code block with following.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    print(self.opp_title)
    self.Event_title.text? = self.opp_title
    self.Txt_event_date.text = self.event_sdate
    self.Event_title.setNeedsDisplay()

    print("event title label \(self.Event_title.text)")
}
```